# WebDriver SwitchTo : Browser pop up not being detected

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

The type of pop up i'm trying to use is here
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/radopen/defaultcs.aspx

I'm trying to just launch the pop up. And enter text in the pop up

I have this page object attempting to handle popups

```
var popUp = function() {

    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles)
    {
       this.originalWindow = handles[0];
       this.newWindow = handles[1];
    })
    this.switchToPopUp = function() {
        browser.switchTo().window(this.newWindow);
    }
    this.switchToOriginal = function() {
        browser.switchTo().window(this.originalWindow);
    }
}
module.exports = new popUp();
```

In my test I have these lines

```
    openRadWindow.click();
    popUp.switchToPopUp();
    browser.element(by.id('ctl00_SearchTextBox').sendKeys("Automation Test List");
```

The error I'm seeing in the trace is
**WebDriver.switchTo().window(undefined)**

Comment: If your application is using the Telerik `RadWindow` object type, that's not a new browser window. It's just a standard HTML element styled to look like a browser window. Use `findElement()`, not `switchTo().window()`.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I've been reading about findElement() vs elementfinder and am a little confused. I initially tried to get the element with elementfinder and couldn't so I moved on to thinking I needed to detect a window. Thanks for the help though! I will try this in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for leading me to the right answer. In my case there is an Iframe brought into the popup so I had to do

```
switchTo.frame('framename')
```